# SQL Exception Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed, When does it get close?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, resultset

The Code:

```
protected List<Object> getAll(Pair<String, Object> primaryKey, String columnLabel) {
    List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        ResultSet resultSet = getRows(primaryKey);
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            objects.add(resultSet.getObject(columnLabel));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        return objects;
    }
}

protected ResultSet getRows(Pair<String, Object> primaryKey) {
    try (Connection con = DataSource.getConnection();
         PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE `" + primaryKey.fst + "` = ?")) {
        pst.setObject(1, primaryKey.snd);
        return pst.executeQuery();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

[Error](https://pastebin.com/SQE35FsK)

Table's columns are: id (int) | player(string) | friend(string)

as id is auto increment.

The error pointing to (line 5):

```
while (resultSet.next()) {
```

when does ResultSet gets closed?

SQLEmmber#getAll(Pair<String, Object> primaryKey, String columnLabel) gets called in [SQLFriends.java](https://pastebin.com/629TdfJu)

Answer (score 0):

Your method `getRows()` uses a try-with-resources block that contains the connection and the prepared statement. At the end of the try-with-resources block, this will explicitly close the prepared statement and the connection.

Closing the prepared statement will close the result set (and closing the connection will close any open statements, and therefor also close any open result sets).

As documented in [`ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html):

> A `ResultSet` object is automatically closed when the `Statement`
> object that generated it is closed, re-executed, or used to retrieve
> the next result from a sequence of multiple results.

You will need to restructure your code so you only close the connection **after** you have retrieved all rows from the result set.